# cant install kivy on chrome os

Tags: python, pip, kivy

when i try to install kivy using pip i get this message:

Collecting https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
Downloading https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
\ 27.1MB 5.8MB/s
Installing build dependencies ... done
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/tmp/pip-req-build-jWrnqi/setup.py", line 427
print(f"OSX framework used, force to {osx_arch} only")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-jWrnqi/

any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: also i amn kinda new to programming

Comment: ok so turns out, no matter which package i try to install, i always get "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in......."

Answer (score 0):

The current `kivy` master [requires](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/f40dd28ed6614d5e1a972fd5a3eeb99e12fa8578/setup.cfg#L12) Python 3.6+. It seems you're using Python 3.5. Please upgrade your Python version or use lower version of `kivy`. Version [1.11.1](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/1.11.1/) supports Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.6. For these older Python version install `kivy`:

```
pip install kivy==1.11.1
```

or

```
pip install "kivy<2.0"
```